# Is it possible to split a http get/post request into many - when invoking it from the client?

Tags: ajax, http, https, get

Here is what I'm doing. Read file content from a content storage server. All I'm doing is invoking a https GET request from the client to fetch the file content.

https://contentserver.xyz.com/file_id (Invoked from client)

file_id - unique value representing a file.

Now my content server has no idea about file meta. So It again makes a call to metaserver to fetch the meta content of the file like

http://metaserver.xyz.com/file_id (Internal S2S communication)

Now is it possible to split this request invoked from client

> https://contentserver.xyz.com/file_id

into two like

> https://contentserver.xyz.com/file_id
>
> https://metaserver.xyz.com/file_id

ie; when the request `https://contentserver.xyz.com/file_id` is invoked the other request `https://metaserver.xyz.com/file_id` should get invoked by default?

I'm not sure whether this could be possible. But curious to know weather there are any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to fetch them in parallel together from client and drop the s2s call?

Comment: yes @amiramw exactly !

Answer (score 0):

When you post an [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) request from javascript on the browser it is sent asynchronously. You pass a callback to when the request is returned successfully or rejected.

So if you post two of them one after the other they are both sent immediately and each of their callbacks will be triggered when finished.

But this is assuming that your content server has no need of the file meta and it just return it to the browser.

Also note that calling a different domain from the browser can indroduce [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the request to file content depends on file meta information, you can't send these 2 requests in parallel. File meta information need to be fetched first.

Otherwise, RxJS can be used to manage these 2 async requests, with `forkJoin`'s help to assemble the result when both *meta* and *content* request are completed.

Here is a simple example:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');

var meta = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer){
  $.get('https://metaserver.xyz.com/file_id', function(data) {
    observer.next(body);
    observer.complete();
  });
});

var content = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer){
  $.get('https://contentserver.xyz.com/file_id', function(data) {
    observer.next(body);
    observer.complete();
  });
});

var source = ['meta', 'content'];
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([meta, content], function(){
  let responseObj = {};
  for(let i=0;i<source.length;i++){
    responseObj[source[i]] = arguments[i];
  }
  return responseObj;
}).subscribe(function(val) {
  // val is the final value, containing meta and content information.
});
```

Please note the `forkJoin` means ([doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)):

> When all observables complete emit the last value from each.